# Redirect in .htaccess makes me cracy

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Following ws call https://training-deluxe.de/nlpdocs/podcast/feed/
should be redirected to podcast hoster podigee

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.training-deluxe.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$

#Whats wrong with the next line
RewriteRule /nlpdocs/podcast/feed/ https://coachingundwissenschaft.podigee.io/feed/mp3 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /coaching_ausbildung/gesundheitscoach_somatic_release_achtsamkeit.html https://rubin-institut.de/health-practitioner-und-gesundheitscoach/ [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^(nlpdocs/.*)$ https://www.rubin-institut.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://rubin-institut.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

Redirect goes to rubin-institut/nlpdocs/podcast...

I cant get the clue

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues...

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.training-deluxe.de/$1 [R=301,L]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
> ```

You need to remove that 2nd/last `RewriteCond` directive above as that will break the rule that follows. `RewriteCond` directives are *conditions* that apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows.

> ```
> #Whats wrong with the next line
> RewriteRule /nlpdocs/podcast/feed/ https://coachingundwissenschaft.podigee.io/feed/mp3 [R=301,L]
> ```

The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive takes a regular expression (regex) - as you've used in later rules. It is not a simple URL-path. And, importantly, in `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. (You have omitted the slash prefix in the later rule that is evidentally "working".)

It should be like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^nlpdocs/podcast/feed/$ https://coachingundwissenschaft.podigee.io/feed/mp3 [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached by the browser. Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

You will also need to check the rule that follows, as that looks like it would have the same problem.

**Reference:**

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @MarkusRoeder You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer (to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue). Once you have 15 rep you can also upvote answers that you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)